# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setState is not a function

Tags: reactjs, api, use-state

I have this error

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): setUsers is not a function
```

And this is what, and how i fetch

```
const { users, setUsers } = useState([]);

  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const data = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10");
    const json = await data.json();
    setUsers(json);
  };
```

**I have no trouble viewing the data in the console but there is a problem when i try to update the state.**

Comment: Wrong set of brackets are used. Use Square brackets for useState. const [ users, setUsers ] = useState([]);

Comment: `{ users, setUsers }` ----> `[ users, setUsers ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must do it like this:

```
const [ users, setUsers ] = useState([]);

const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const data = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10");
    const json = await data.json();
    setUsers(json);
};
```

Because `useState()` returns an array.

Comment: Right haha. Thank you! I don't know how i missed that

Comment: @Frontmaniaac if it's ok, accept answer to clear question